# how to take 10000 character string input in java

Tags: java

I need to take a 10000 character string as input from user in a program in java. But when i use the normal way it gives NZEC error in ideone and spoj. How can i take such a string as an input ?

```
import java.io.*;
class st
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
         String a;
         BufferedReader g=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         a=g.readLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: What do you mean by "it gives NZEC error"?

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436207/runtime-error-nzec-in-simple-code

Comment: That's over 9000! Do you really need all the string at once? If you pass it to a library/third party module for parsing - can they accept streams? If you parse it yourself - can you modify your code to parse a stream instead?

Comment: I need a 10000 character string as an input from the user which is not happening in this normal way...

Comment: Have you looked at the link provided by `fujy` about [SPOJ](http://www.spoj.com/) specifics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read until the buffer is full.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(System.in);
dis.readFully(buffer);
// Once you get here, the buffer is filled with the input of stdin.
String str = new String(buffer);
```

Comment: would you please explain it in a easy way.... i need it for string.... and please show me a code which will just input and display a big String also which will work on ideone....

Comment: Ideone will work but you will have to supply at least 10000 bytes of input in the website. I don't know if it is allowed to add such a large input.

Answer (score 1):

BufferedReader uses a buffer that is large enough "for most purposes".  10000 characters is probably too large.  Since you're using readLine, the reader is scanning characters read, looking for an end of line.  After its internal buffer is full, and it still hasn't found an end of line, it throws an exception.

You could try setting the size of the buffer when you create the BufferedReader:

```
BufferedReader g=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in), 10002);
```

Or you could use use

```
BufferedReader.read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)
```

instead.  That would give you an array of char, and you'd need to convert it back to a String.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Runtime Error (NZEC) in simple code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436207/runtime-error-nzec-in-simple-code) to understand possible reasons for the error message.

I suggest you wrap the readLine() in a try/catch block and print the error message / stack trace.

Comment: maybe it was coming because the limit for this input is not 10000 characters while the input is that big....

Comment: What was the exception that was raised?  Or did it fail without throwing one?

Comment: BufferedReader uses a buffer that is large enough "for most purposes".  10000 characters is probably too large.